# How do I group multiples of an array of json objects into new objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of json objects that I need grouped together by four to create an single object. Ultimately my goal is to use OPENJSON in SQL Sever to insert the values into a table with each object being a row.

It seems like it should be simple enough. I have been searching the web a lot and I have run across various things such as _.groupBy(), $.extend(true, {}, x, y); etc. But none of it seems to do quite what I want.

I have the following array of JSON objects:

```
[{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"04/29/2019"},{"name":"intStps","value":"1"}, 
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}, 
{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"04/30/2019"},{"name":"intStps","value":"1"}, 
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}, 
{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"05/01/2019"},{"name":"intStps","value":"1"}, 
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}, 
{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"05/02/2019"},{"name":"intStps","value":"1"}, 
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}, 
{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"05/03/2019"},{"name":"intStps","value":"1"}, 
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}]
```

I need the grouped as such:

```
Object {
{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"04/29/2019"},
{"name":"intStps","value":"1"},
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}
},
Object {
{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"04/30/2019"},
{"name":"intStps","value":"1"},
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}
},
Object {
{"name":"locMLR","value":"6485183463415278686"}, 
{"name":"dayDate","value":"05/01/2019"},{"name":"intStps","value":"1"}, 
{"name":"intPkgs","value":"2"}
}
```

Comment: The grouped object syntax is invalid - do you mean for it to be an array of arrays? Could you also provide us with what you've tried so far?

Comment: Do you really want to end up with an object? If so you need keys for the 4 groups not just the word object. It would make more sense to have an matrix. like so [ [group1 ], [group2 ], [group3 ]. [group4 ]  ]

Comment: *"grouped together by four to create a single object"* This is unclear. Please post a valid output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really grouping in the classic sense, I would do something like this:

```js
const originalData = [
    {
        "name": "locMLR",
        "value": "6485183463415278686"
    },
    {
        "name": "dayDate",
        "value": "04/29/2019"
    }, {
        "name": "intStps",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "intPkgs",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "locMLR",
        "value": "6485183463415278686"
    },
    {
        "name": "dayDate",
        "value": "04/30/2019"
    }, {
        "name": "intStps",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "intPkgs",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "locMLR",
        "value": "6485183463415278686"
    },
    {
        "name": "dayDate",
        "value": "05/01/2019"
    }, {
        "name": "intStps",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "intPkgs",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "locMLR",
        "value": "6485183463415278686"
    },
    {
        "name": "dayDate",
        "value": "05/02/2019"
    }, {
        "name": "intStps",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "intPkgs",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "locMLR",
        "value": "6485183463415278686"
    },
    {
        "name": "dayDate",
        "value": "05/03/2019"
    }, {
        "name": "intStps",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "intPkgs",
        "value": "2"
    }
];

const groupedData = [];
let groupedItem = [];
originalData.forEach((data, index) => {
    groupedItem.push(data);
    if (index % 4 === 3) {
        groupedData.push(groupedItem);
        groupedItem = [];
    }
});
console.log(groupedData);
```

Comment: This works, although I'll admit Scott Sauyet's answer is better but I'm not sure why you downvoted it

Comment: i was going to ask as well.  I also prefer my solution.  ( :-) ) but this seems perfectly reasonable. (One thing I would fix, though, is to make this into a snippet.  If the code is easily runnable here, you might as well show it running!)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a function like this `chunk`, which takes the chunk size and an array and groups the elements in chunks that size:

```js
const chunk = (n, arr, res = []) => arr.length == 0
  ? res
  : chunk (n, arr.slice(n), res.concat([arr.slice(0, n)]))

const arr = [{"name": "locMLR", "value": "6485183463415278686"}, {"name": "dayDate", "value": "04/29/2019"}, {"name": "intStps", "value": "1"}, {"name": "intPkgs", "value": "2"}, {"name": "locMLR", "value": "6485183463415278686"}, {"name": "dayDate", "value": "04/30/2019"}, {"name": "intStps", "value": "1"}, {"name": "intPkgs", "value": "2"}, {"name": "locMLR", "value": "6485183463415278686"}, {"name": "dayDate", "value": "05/01/2019"}, {"name": "intStps", "value": "1"}, {"name": "intPkgs", "value": "2"}, {"name": "locMLR", "value": "6485183463415278686"}, {"name": "dayDate", "value": "05/02/2019"}, {"name": "intStps", "value": "1"}, {"name": "intPkgs", "value": "2"}, {"name": "locMLR", "value": "6485183463415278686"}, {"name": "dayDate", "value": "05/03/2019"}, {"name": "intStps", "value": "1"}, {"name": "intPkgs", "value": "2"}]

console.log(chunk(4, arr))
```

There are plenty of alternative ways to write this.  But this recursive solution is clean and straightforward, and if and when your JS engine performs tail-call optimization, it should be relatively efficient.

### Update

If you want to do this without the recursive call, you can fold the array with `reduce` like this:

```js
const chunk = (n, xs) => xs.reduce(
  (a, x, i) => i % n == 0 
    ? a.concat([[x]]) 
    : a.slice(0, -1).concat([a.slice(-1)[0].concat(x)]), 
  []
)
```

But to me that's quite a bit less readable.